# Colorize the PS4 prompt?

Tags: bash, colors, prompt, ansi-term

With the option `set -x`, each command is echoed to STDERR before execution, prefixed by the expanded `$PS4`, with the first character being repeated according to the call stack depth.

I want the output of the `$PS4` prompt to be colorized. I.e. where

```
(set -x; ls -l)
```

will currently print

```
+ ls -l
```

I want an output

```
\033[90m+ ls -l\033[0m
      \              \
       \              `- Reset color
        `- Muted gray
```

However, with PS4 being printed before echoing the command, I can't think of a method to reset the color with `\033[0m` *before* the command is executed.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: Consider using a `DEBUG` trap instead of `set -x`. Example: `set -T; trap 'printf "%*s\e[90m+%s\e[m\n" "$((${#FUNCNAME[*]}*2))" "" "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG`

Comment: @mosvy While it works, it doesn't come close to the convenience of `set -x` / `bash -x myscript`. Though I can imagine doing something like `setx () { <your code>; }; export -f setx` in `.bashrc`, and using `(setx; debug this)` and `bash -c 'setx; source myscript'`. Using PS4 however would have the advantage, that it can be inherited by scripts without having to change them.

Comment: I'm sorry you find that so inconvenient. With real scripts (not `-c` or stdin), you can use `export BASH_ENV` to make them execute commands upon start-up.

Comment: correction: with newer versions of bash (eg. 5.0.3) `BASH_ENV` will also be sourced by scripts given via `-c` or read from stdin,

Comment: @user313992, IMO it's a good answer based on OP's question, so should be posted as an answer (and some elaboration on the syntax would be great too)